# Can I mix C++ and Swift in the same swift package, using the Swift Package Manager?

Tags: c++, swift, swift-package-manager

I would like to write one module in C++, and make some functions in C that are accessible in Swift.

I am somewhat baffled, because no matter what I do, the SPM insists on attempting to compile the C++ code as if it were Objective-C, and of course it cannot find the right headers.

Here is my attempt.

Source directory structure:

```
Sources
|
+-CxxModule
| |
| +-include
| | |
| | +-CxxModule.hpp
| |
| +-CxxModule.cpp
|
+-SwiftModule
  |
  +-SwiftModule.swift
```

The manifest `Package.swift` is as follows:

```
// swift-tools-version: 5.6

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "CxxLibrary",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "CxxLibrary",
            targets: ["SwiftModule"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "CxxModule",
            dependencies: []),
        .target(
            name: "SwiftModule",
            dependencies: ["CxxModule"],
            path: "Sources/SwiftModule"
        ),
    ]
)
```

`CxxModule.hpp` is as follows:

```
#ifndef CxxModule_hpp
#define CxxModule_hpp

#include <iostream>

extern "C" void printHello();

#endif /* CxxModule_hpp */
```

`CxxModule.cpp` is as follows:

```
#include "CxxModule.hpp"

void printHello() {
    // use something from the standard library to make sure
    // c++ is really being used
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}
```

Finally, `SwiftModule.swift`:

```
import CxxModule
```

What am I missing? Is there a way to tell SPM that the module is supposed to be in C++? Or is this simply unsupported at the moment?

Note: the C++ compiles just fine if I eliminate the Swift target.

Answer (score 3):

#### Updated answer for Swift 5.9+

Swift 5.9 supports interoperability with C++. Therefore, there is no longer any need to craft a special header that compiles both in C and C++. Instead, C++ interoperability mode should be enabled by adding `.interoperabilityMode(.Cxx)` to each target’s `swiftSettings` in the `Package.swift` manifest. Here is the updated manifest:

```swift
// swift-tools-version: 5.9

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "CxxLibrary",
    // To avoid linker warnings in macOS, make version 13 (or later, 
    // according to your needs), the minimum supported version:
    platforms: [.macOS(.v13)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "CxxLibrary",
            targets: ["SwiftModule"]
        ),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "CxxModule"
        ),
        .target(
            name: "SwiftModule",
            dependencies: ["CxxModule"],
            // Specifying the path is superfluous as long as
            // the corresponding folder is called 'SwiftModule'
            swiftSettings: [.interoperabilityMode(.Cxx)]
        ),
    ]
)
```

The file structure remains unchanged. However, I modified `CxxModule.hpp` and `CxxModule.cpp` as follows:

`CxxModule.hpp`:

```cpp
#ifndef CxxModule_hpp
#define CxxModule_hpp

void printHello();

#endif /* CxxModule_hpp */
```

`CxxModule.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void printHello() {
    // use something from the standard library to make sure
    // c++ is really being used
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}
```

With C++ interoperability, there is now no problem importing functions and classes directly from C++, with some [restrictions](https://www.swift.org/documentation/cxx-interop/#using-c-types-and-functions-in-swift). The complete guide can be found at https://www.swift.org/documentation/cxx-interop/.

#### Old answer for Swift <= 5.9

I was able to resolve the problem. The answer is “Yes” so long as the header exposed to Swift is readable in pure C.

First, I moved all C++-specific code (especially headers referencing the standard library) into the source `cpp` file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CxxModule.hpp"

void printHello() {
    // use something from the standard library to make sure
    // c++ is really being used
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}
```

Second, I added macros to make the header readable in both C and C++:

```
#ifndef CxxModule_hpp
#define CxxModule_hpp

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void printHello();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* CxxModule_hpp */
```

The file structure and Swift module remain unchanged.

The lesson: any header that is going to be read by both C++ and Swift must be readable by both. (Swift is able to understand C headers, but not C++ headers, at least in its present state.)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of notes for other people struggling with C and Swift (for C++ is "simply" a matter of naming.. I do know, but without a functioning C code, C++ is mission impossible..)

to recap:

1. suppose You have "C" code, let call it generically libC (a folder), that contains both *.c and *.h files.
2. You want to build a wrapper, say libCWrapper
3. build a package in Xcode names libCWrapper
4. Xcode should build a Package.swift similar to: (comments removed)

```
import PackageDescription
    
let package = Package(
  name: "libCWrapper",
  products: [
    .library(
      name: "libCWrapper",
      targets: ["libCWrapper"]),
    ],
  targets: [
    .target(
      name: "libCWrapper",
      dependencies: []),
  .testTarget(
    name: "libCWrapperTests",
    dependencies: ["libCWrapper"]),
  ]
)
```

5. now first trick: we need TWO targets and TWO products.. so add:

```
products: [
  .library( name: "libCWrapper", targets: ["libCWrapper"]),
  .library( name: "libC", targets: ["libC"]),
],

..


  .target(
    name: "libCWrapper",
    dependencies: ["libC"]),
        
  .target(
    name: "libC",
    dependencies: []),
```

**Note:**
swift libCWrapper depends ON libC.

6. we must also Add/change layout of "C sources:

all "C" code must go inside a fodder names as "C" target, but include one level UP. So:

Sources
--->[libC]
sampleCall.c
[include]
---> [sampleCall.h]

so:

[image]

7. pls add also targets, I f You need to make some tests:

   platforms: [
   .macOS(.v10_12), .iOS(.v9)],
8. inside tests:

@testable import libCWrapper
**@testable import libC**

Add the C product, TOO.
so tests can be:

```
import XCTest
@testable import libCWrapper
@testable import libC

final class libCWrapperTests: XCTestCase {
    
    func testExample() throws {
        // This is an example of a functional test case.
        // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct
        // results.
        XCTAssertEqual(libCWrapper().text, "Hello, World!")
    }
    
    func testGimmeFive(){
        let n = gimmeFive()
        XCTAssertEqual(n, 5)

    }
}
```

where in C we have:

```
//
//  sampleCall.c.c
//  
//
//  Created by ing.conti on 24/08/22.
//

#include "sampleCall.h"


int gimmeFive(void){
    return 5;
}
```

now, as You can call C from swift in test, is only a matter of "open" / "public" and similar.